# switching postgresl databases in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just made a local backup of my database in heroku (named 'mylocaldb') and am trying to have my application now point to that database rather than the databases it created when I made the app.

Do I just need to change the development db to 'mylocaldb' or is there anything else? I made this change and ran a migrate but I still can't see the data from it in my application when I run it on web brick.

```
development:
  database: mylocaldb
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need the `adapter` to be “postgresql”.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mylocaldb
  username: my_login
```

---

If you will use the same database for testing then it may be worthwhile to change the default:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```